# How to handle an rxjs observable response that could be empty?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I'm using Angular2 and Ionic2 with typescript and would like to handle a response from the backend service where I can get

- an empty response with http 200
- or a json object containing an errormessage property with information to be displayed to the user.

This is my request:

```
this.http.put(***).subscribe((data) => {
```

The problem is that if I give the data parameter, rxjs tries to serialize it from json and if that is empty, it throws an error. If I don't give the data parameter I can handle the empty response but how will I reach the errormessage property if I have one?

I don't want to request change on the backend side to give proper http error codes in case of error. Is there a way I can handle this?

Comment: have you tried to implement on error methid ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
public Update = (itemToUpdate: any): Observable<Response> => {
    return this._http
        .put("htto://localhost/api/", JSON.stringify(itemToUpdate))
        .map(res => res ? res.json() : {});
}
```

Comment: Yeah I should have tried map before asking. :) Thanks!

Comment: happy to helped you!